# Jquery:Autocomplete with .each()

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, each

I'm trying to add autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) with .each().

[I have a FIDDLE with it not working.](http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/ajuHL/)

Basically multiple inputs with same id and with same autocomplete data.

Jquery:

```
 $(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
     $("#tags").each(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
         });
     });
});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID of an element should be unique, so it is not possible, change the id to a class.

If there are multiple elements with the same id, the id-selector will return the first element with the id, it will not look for other elements

Also there is no need to use `.each()` here, you can just say `$(".tags").autocomplete(...)`, the widget will do the iteration internally

```
Input
<input class="tags" />
Another Input
<input class="tags" />
```

Then

```
$(".tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H675B/)

Comment: This works thank you, but do you have a better explanation? http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/ajuHL/1/

Comment: @msbodetti An ID selector will only ever match the first occurrence, as there should only be one match in the first place (they are "identifiers"). If you need to have multiple items with the same reference, you need to use a class - thus, you mark all the items as sharing a particular classification.

Comment: Thanks! Will accept this answer and thank you for explaining @AdrianWragg and to Arun